# Spark Analysis using Scala

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, rdd

```
val lines=KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String,String,StringDecoder,StringDecoder](ssc,kafkaParams,topics).map(_._2)

val data1 = ssc.cassandraTable("test","login").where("email=?","abc@xyz.com")

val f =data1.first

println(f)

val s =f.getString("email")

println(s)

lines.foreachRDD{rdd =>rdd.foreach { println

//if(s==rd)

//convert(rdd=>rdd.toString)

//rdd.collect()

}}
```

How can I compare `rdd` (Unit) variable with `s` (String)?

For instance value stored in s is:

```
abc@xyz.com
```

And value stored in rdd is :

```
"abc@xyz.com"
```

I tried comparing it normally with if condition, it gives the following error

```
type mismatch;

[error]  found   : String
[error]  required: String => Unit
```

Any kind of help is appreciated .

Comment: It will be very helpful if you can tell a bit about your usecase, what kind of message you are getting through kafka? and what finally you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lines.foreachRDD{rdd =>rdd.foreach {

rdd => func_call(rdd)
}}

def func_call(s:String){

//Here the returned rdd can be treated as String and can be compared to the other string
}